# How to resolve ignoring ref with broken name of deleted branch

Tags: git, branch, conflict

I've gotten myself into some branch troubles and ended up deleting everything related to this branch, on GitHub as well as locally but I keep getting:

```
$ git branch
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/heads/deleted_branch (conflicted copy 2020-12-18 151952)
```

I've done `git branch -d  deleted_branch`, `git branch -D  deleted_branch`, deleted the branch on GitHub(followed by `fetch` & `pull`) but that `deleted_branch` seems to be sticking around. How do I get this resolved?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This name:

```
deleted_branch (conflicted copy 2020-12-18 151952)
```

looks like the kind of thing created by sharing systems like Dropbox.

Git needs *full control* of its own repository.  **Never place a Git repository in a shared folder.**<sup>1</sup>  Git has its own mechanism for doing properly-controlled sharing, which we achieve with `git fetch` and `git push`.  (You might hide your `git fetch` behind `git pull`, but it's still a `git fetch`.)

> How do I [delete the bad branch name]?

The bad name is not `deleted_branch` but rather `deleted branch (conflicted copy 2020-12-18 151952)`.  It's possible that the only way to delete it is to do it manually.

First, though, make sure the Git repository is out of reach of all non-Git programs that might automatically fiddle with it and try to resolve conflicted copies of files.  In other words, get the Git repository *out* of any shared folders.  Note that the Git repository proper is normally in the `.git` sub-directory (sub-folder) of the top level of your working tree.  If you move the entire working tree, including all its sub-folders, that will also move the Git repository.

Now you can try `git branch -d "deleted branch (conflicted copy 2020-12-18 151952)"`, where the double quotes protect the parentheses and whitespace from your shell.  If this works, that's good.  If not, you will need the manual method.

You can enter the repository itself: the `.git` folder.  Inside this folder (directory), there is a sub-folder named `refs`.  Inside that there is another sub-directory named `heads`.  This second subdirectory contains files for each "active" branch.  Listing the contents of the directory should turn up the bad name.  For instance, in a good Git repository on one of my machines, I get:

```
$ ls -l .git/refs/heads
total 4
-rw-r--r--  ... 41 Dec 13 07:47 master
```

(this repository has only one active branch, named `master`).  Note that I didn't actually bother entering the `.git` directory; I'm doing these from the top level of the work-tree, using `.git/refs/` to get access to the files there.

If the bad name turns up here:

```
-rw-r--r--  ... 41 <date> deleted_branch (conflicted copy 2020-12-18 151952)
```

you can then remove it with your system's file-removing tool.  On this box (Linux/Unix-like), that's `rm`:

```
$ rm ".git/refs/heads/deleted_branch (conflicted copy 2020-12-18 151952)"
```

The quotes protect the parentheses and spaces from the shell, so that the `rm` command gets the whole name.  This removes the internal file that holds the branch hash ID—these are each 40 bytes long, which is why the size is 41 bytes: 40 bytes plus a newline—and having removed the file, the branch should now be gone.

If it's *not* gone or wasn't there in the first place, it's possible that Git has "packed" the ref as well.  In this case, open the file `.git/packed-refs` in a text editor that won't mangle the contents (won't turn it into UTF-16-LE, nor add byte-order-markers, nor change line endings to CRLF instead of LF-only, and the like).  Remove the line that corresponds to the bad branch name and save the file (still as plain text).

---

<sup>1</sup>What, never?  <insert entire G&S routine here>  There are some rare situations where you *can* do this, as long as you know exactly what you're doing and all about how Git works internally, but even then it's generally a bad idea.  I've done it with VirtualBox VMs as an experiment, and it can work, but it gets very slow sometimes—so slow that it's better to just use Git's fetch/push system.